# Jackson failing on deserializing empty array

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have serialized and then tried to deserialize empty array using jacksons library

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

List<Integer> original = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Writer w = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(w, original);

String encoded = w.toString();
Object decoded = mapper.readValue(encoded, Object.class); // THIS LINE THROWS
```

But last line fails with error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
```

But when I remove line with `enableDefaultTyping` function then everyting works fine.

Is it me using this library wrong or is it library bug?

Comment: Try like this Object decoded = encoded != null ? mapper.readValue(encoded, Object.class); : "{}";

Comment: @PradeepSekar what are you talking about? readValue throws exception because it can not decode string "[]"

Answer (score 0):

[To get the generic ArrayListType:](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);
List<Integer> original = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String encoded = mapper.writeValueAsString(original);
Object decoded = mapper.readValue(encoded, Object.class); 
/*Results in encoded: ["java.util.ArrayList",[]] */
```

For preserving list types reference [5.1 Missing type information on Serialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) in the jackson wiki

> There are multiple ways to solve this:
>
> - Use arrays instead of Lists: MyPojo[] would retain type information
> - Sub-class list, using class MyPojoList extends ArrayList { }     -- type information will be retained due to inheritance
>     ("super-type token")
> - Force use of specific root type (reference wiki link)

Comment: I want to add type anotation node only to Objects ({}) but not to arrays or lists ([]). I also do not know what type I am deserializing because I get just a string. Is this possible with jackson

Comment: So is it that you have x # of object types that you are expecting and you want to de-serialize based on the type key sent with the serialized(json) object? In your example you mention wanting to serialize and deserialize an ArrayList. Please update with new example